# WCF Service known type object won't return properties of the known type

Tags: vb.net, wcf, object, known-types

I have created a WCF service and have two particular objects, Contact and Driver. Driver inherits Contact. The Contact object is part of a larger Member object. In the code I have the following:

```
<DataContract()>
Public Class Contact
    <DataMember()>
    Public Name As String
    <DataMember()>
    Public HomePhone As String
    ... etc.
End Class

<DataContract()>
Public Class Driver
    Inherits Contact
    <DataMember()>
    Public LicenseNum As String
    <DataMember()>
    Public LicenseState As String
    ... etc.
End Class

<DataContract(), KnownType(GetType(Driver))>
Public Class Member
    <DataMember()>
    Public Info As Contact
    <DataMember()>
    Public PrimaryStore As Store
    ... etc.
End Class
```

Because I have the knowntype on the datacontract line, I can create a Member object with the Info property as a Driver instead of a Contact so I can save their license information.

My problem is that when I create a test project to see the returned data, I can't get the license information when I call the Info property.

```
Dim svc as New Service.RetrieveService
Dim sMember as Member
Dim memNum as String = "ABC123"
sMember = svc.GetMember(memNum)
Console.WriteLine("LicenseNumber" & sMember.Info...PROBLEM!!!)
```

sMember.Info only gives me properties belonging to Contact (Name, HomePhone, etc.) and none belonging to Driver (LicenseNum, LicenseState, etc.) How can I access this info?

I have already tried to add ServiceKnownType to my OperationContract as below:

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface RetrieveMember
    <OperationContract(), ServiceKnownType(GetType(Driver))>
    Function GetMember(ByVal memberNumber as String) As Member
End Interface
```

but it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the `Member.Info` property is defined as the `Contact` type.  That means, even if it references a `Driver` object, it will still be cast as a `Contact` object, so only those base members will be visible.  This is a problem which is unrelated to WCF.  For instance, even removing WCF from the situation, you'd still have the same problem:

```
Dim m As New Member()
m.Info = New Driver()
Console.WriteLine(m.Contact.LicenseNum)  ' Won't compile!
```

So, if the `Info` property is referencing a `Driver` object, you must cast it to that type before you can access any of the `Driver` members:

```
Dim m As Member
' ...
If TypeOf m.Info Is Driver Then
    Dim d As Driver = CType(m.Info, Driver)
    Console.WriteLine(d.LicenseNum)  ' Works fine
End if
```

Comment: That worked! I was just wondering if there was some new way since it was a WCF service being called. Makes me wonder how the person calling your service would know that these particular items were cast differently than the service shows.